# Perl Soap service using wsdl

Tags: web-services, perl, wsdl, soap-client, soapserver

I am trying to create SOAP service using SOAP::Lite, but it does not return the value. It gives Error Use of uninitialized value $result in print at soap_client.pl line 6.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.187:80>
 ServerName perl.qlc.net
 ServerAlias www.perl.qlc.net
 DocumentRoot /web/perl.qlc.net/htdocs
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/perl.qlc.net_error_log
 TransferLog /var/log/httpd/perl.qlc.net_access_log
      <Directory "/web/perl.qlc.net/htdocs">
        <FilesMatch "\.mhtml$|\.pl$|\.html$">
                Options         +ExecCGI
                AddHandler      cgi-script .cgi .pl .html
                SetHandler      perl-script
                PerlHandler     ModPerl::Registry
                PerlSendHeader  On
        </FilesMatch>
      </Directory>
 DirectoryIndex index.phtml index.htm index.html index.php3 index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

**Installed perl modules:**

```
MIME::Parser
SOAP::Lite
```

**Apache module:**

```
mod_perl
```

**Soap server: math.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
#use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

print "Content-type:text/xml\r\n\r\n";
#I have added above line because apache was throwing 500 error.

my $soap = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI->new(
    dispatch_to => 'Arithmetic'
);
$soap->handle(); 

package Arithmetic;
sub add {
        return $_[1] + $_[2];
}
1;
```

**Soap client: soap_client.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#use SOAP::Lite +trace =>'debug';
use SOAP::Lite;
my $result = 0;
my $client = SOAP::Lite->service("http://perl.qlc.net/math.wsdl");
print $result = $client->add(10, 20);
```

**Wsdl file: math.wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://perl.qlc.net/math.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="HelloService" targetNamespace="http://perl.qlc.net/math.wsdl">
<message name="addRequest">
    <part name="operand1" type="xsd:float" />
    <part name="operand2" type="xsd:float" />
</message>
<message name="addResponse">
    <part name="response" type="xsd:float" />
</message>
<portType name="Hello_PortType">
    <operation name="add">
        <input message="tns:addRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:addResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="add">
        <soap:operation soapAction="add"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:helloservice" use="encoded"/>
        </input>
        <output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:helloservice" use="encoded"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Hello_Service">
<documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
<port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
    <soap:address location="http://perl.qlc.net/math.pl"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

When I run soap_client.pl it gives me following error:
Use of uninitialized value $result in print at soap_client.pl line 6.
I have been trying this for 2 day, not getting any clue where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem has been solved by modifying math.wsdl
**Modified math.wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:Arithmetic" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="HelloService" targetNamespace="urn:Arithmetic" xmlns:y="urn:Arithmetic">
<message name="addRequest">
    <part name="operand1" type="xsd:float" />
    <part name="operand2" type="xsd:float" />
</message>
<message name="addResponse">
    <part name="response" type="xsd:float" />
</message>
<portType name="Hello_PortType">
    <operation name="add">
        <input message="tns:addRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:addResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="add">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Arithmetic#add"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:Arithmetic" use="encoded"/>
        </input>
        <output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:Arithmetic" use="encoded"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Hello_Service">
<documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
<port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
    <soap:address location="http://perl.qlc.net/math.pl"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the result method to get the result:

```
$client->add(10, 20)->result;
```

In addition, you should probably add some error handling to check if the command succeeded before you use the result:

```
my $added = $client->add(10,20);
unless (defined $added)
{
    die "Failed add: $!";
}
$result = $added->result;
```

Also, are you using a .net server by any chance?  The `Soap::Lite` documentation [makes some specific recommendations in that case](http://search.cpan.org/~mkutter/SOAP-Lite-0.715/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm#SOAP%3a%3aLite_client_with_a_.NET_server), and recommends against using the above format.

Comment: It throws error. Can't call method "result" on an undefined value at soap_client.pl line 6

Comment: @pankajghadge, that indicates the original command failed.  After the command, check the contents of `$!`.

Comment: If i give a call to php soap server using same perl script soap_client.pl. It gives me the correct result. I think some thing is wrong with soap server script.